# Application of Sobolev's inequality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, lebesgue-integral

Given $K\subset \mathbb{R}$ compact, we consider a regular function $f:K^n\to \mathbb{R}$ whose mean value is $0$. I was wondering if we can get the inequality $ n\|f\|_{L^q(K^n)}\leq C \sum_{i=1}^n\|\nabla_{x_i}f\|_{L^2(K^n)}$ for some $C$ that only depends on $K$ (not on $n$), where $q$ satisfies $1/q=1/2-1/n.$

I suppose that if this is true, it should be a consequence of applying [Sobolev inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality) . However, the constant here depends on $n$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you think this should be a consequence of the Sobolev inequality? The Sobolev inequality usually requires $f\in H^1_0(K)$ not mean zero. For functions with mean zero the "usual" inequality is the Poincaré-Wirtinger inequality, but this doesn't seem to get you what you want

Comment: Sobolev inequalities with zero mean do exist. They are sometimes indeed called Poincare-Sobolev inequalities. See e.g Theorem 8.12 in *Analysis* by Lieb and Loss.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to mean the Poincare-Sobolev inequalities

Answer (score 1):

This is false.

Take $f(x_1,\dots,x_n) = g(x_1)\,\dots g(x_n)$ with $g$ with $0$ mean and with $\|g\|_{L^2} = 1$, $\|g\|_{L^q} > 1$ and $\|\nabla g\|_{L^2} < \infty$. Then your inequality would imply that for every $n\in\Bbb N$,
$$
n \,\|g\|_{L^q(K)}^n \leq C\,\sum_{j=1}^n \|\nabla g\|_{L^2(K)} = C\,n\, \|\nabla g\|_{L^2(K)}
$$
and so
$$
\|g\|_{L^q(K)}^n \leq C\, \|\nabla g\|_{L^2(K)}.
$$
Letting $n\to\infty$ gives $\|g\|_{L^q(K)}^n\to\infty$ contradicting the fact that $\|\nabla g\|_{L^2}<\infty$.

Comment: I don't see how you obtain that. If I try to apply the inequality to your example, I obtain $$n\|g\|_{L^q}\leq C \sum_{j=1}^{n}\|  \nabla_{x_i}g \|_{L^2}\| g \|_{L^2}^{n-1}=C n \| \nabla_{x_i}g \|_{L^2}\| g \|_{L^2}^{n-1}$$

Comment: I chose $g$ so that $\|g\|_{L^2} =1$. And you are missing the power $n$ on the $L^q$ norm.